# WPF doing number substitution on title

Tags: xaml

When I create a simply WPF application that has a number in the title "4More" for example the text will stay as "4More" when run on an English version of Windows. When I run it on an Arabic version of Windows it stays as "4More". However when I change the flow direction to RTL and run on Arabic it starts doing number substitution changing the European 4 to the Arabic 4 (٤). I would like to be able to control the number substitution for the title of the window.

I have applied the NumberSubstitution.Substitution="European" onto the window but it did not make a difference.

Here is my XAML code as it stands:

```
<Window x:Class="TestTitle.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestTitle"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="4More"
Height="350"
Width="525"
FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
NumberSubstitution.Substitution="European">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What do I need to do to get it show the European number 4 in the title?

Comment: The standard Arabic Windows release flows right-to-left, or vice versa?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but will it respect straight ascii/unicode? `&#52;More`

Comment: @MarioVernari Yes, that is the standard for Arabic Windows. Windows Explorer has the minimize, maximize, and close buttons on the left.

Comment: @ChrisW. No joy. Still shows as ٤More